# Tkinter, explanation on tag and search method

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this small piece of code that i want a clarification for

```
        count=IntVar()
        s=w.txt.search(self.entry.get(),'1.0',stopindex=END,count=count)
        txt.tag_configure("match",background='yellow')
        end=f'{s}+{count.get()}c'
        txt.tag_add("match",s,end)
```

i want to know , when search is successful, it return `1.0` when it is not it give an error,about tag, i want to understand `end` variable, how does it help to find the match and highlight it,one last thing is: what is the difference between `IntVar()` and `StringVar()` they seem to be similar to me and i might be mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote *"I want to know, when search is successful, it return 1.0 "*, but that is incorrect. `search` returns the index where the string was found. It might be "1.0" but it could be any valid index.

`stopindex` tells tkinter to stop searching when it reaches that index. Otherwise the search could wrap around to the beginning of the text.

From the canonical [tcl/tk documentaton](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M120):

> If *stopIndex* is specified, the search stops at that index: for
> forward searches, no match at or after stopIndex will be considered;
> for backward searches, no match earlier in the text than *stopIndex*
> will be considered. If *stopIndex* is omitted, the entire text will be
> searched: when the beginning or end of the text is reached, the search
> continues at the other end until the starting location is reached
> again; if *stopIndex* is specified, no wrap-around will occur. This
> means that, for example, if the search is -forwards but *stopIndex* is
> earlier in the text than *startIndex*, nothing will ever be found.

The `end` variable is a temporary variable used to define the range of text matched by search. It is computed by adding to the starting index the number of characters that `search` matched. Search will update the `count` variable with that number.

In your code, if `s` is "2.0" and `count.get()` returns 5, `end` will be set to "2.0+5c". With the text widget, indexes can be specified with modifiers. In this case "2.0 +5c" or "2.0 +2 characters" means "index 2.0 plus 5 characters".

Using `count` is most useful when doing a regular expression search where the number of characters matched may be longer or shorter than the expression being searched for.

The difference between `IntVar` and `StringVar` is that when you call the `get` method, an instance of `IntVar` will always return an integer or throw an exception if the value isn't a number. Calling `get` on an instance of `StringVar` will always return a string. `IntVar` is just a convenience wrapper around `StringVar` to automatically convert the returned value as an integer.

Comment: what about 'c' that is added at the end of variable ```end```?

Comment: @ghazigamer: I've updated my answer to address that.